# Cross product for vector angular position?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, classical-mechanics, cross-product

The angular velocity of a particle $\omega = r \times v$ is a pseudovector because it is formed by the cross product of two vectors (position and linear velocity).

Likewise the angular acceleration of a particle $\alpha = r \times a$ is a pseudovector.

This implies to me that the angular position $\theta$ is ALSO a pseudovector.  The only way I knowing of telling whether a given quality is a pseudovector, though, is if it has a cross product representation.

Looking at the form of the cross products which define $\omega$ and $\alpha$ might momentarily lead one to believe that the product must be $\theta = r\times r$, until you realize that that would imply that $\theta$ is always $0$.

My question is is there a cross product representation of the angular position of a particle?

Comment: You can observe what happens by $r \to -r$. In case of $\omega$ nothing, so it is axial, non-polar.

Comment: It should properly be $|r|^2·ω=r×v$ to be the angular velocity, not the area velocity. $ω$ defines a direction in the lie-algebra of the rotations or equivalently on the quaternion unit sphere, both are embedded in linear spaces other than $\Bbb R^3$, so discussion of orientation has also to be lifted to this context.

Answer (score 1):

No, angular position is no vector, just a scalar. The closest vector description is via $\omega$, which is orthogonal to the plane of rotation, honouring the right hand rule.

$\omega$ is an axial vector, as it will not change if $r=(x,y,z) \to -r = (-x,-y,-z)$.

Comment: That answer probably means [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem#Generators_of_rotations)